# Django RF, validation of input data in view layer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I wanted to get the `date` or `tablerequireDate` argument  from the POST requests, how do I achieve in the below view layer ?

VIEWS.PY

```
class Tablecreateview(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Tables.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Tableserializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        request_user = self.request.user 
        serializer.save(author=request_user)
```

MODELS.PY

```
class Tables(models.Model):

    tablerequiretime = models.TimeField()
    tablerequireDate = models.DateField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updatedat = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    foodliketoeat = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    totalpersons = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(20)])
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author.username
```

SERIALIZERS.PY

```
class Tableserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Tables
        exclude=('author',)
```

Comment: Hi Guys, should I do validations in serializes instead of view layer ?

Comment: yes Serializers are designed to valiidate post request data

Comment: do you want the date before the creation performing?

Comment: yes,I wanted to validate the tablerequireddate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay you can access this field before `perform_create` takes place

```
class Tablecreateview(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Tables.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Tableserializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        tablerequireDate = serializer.data['tablerequireDate']
        # Do you magic then perform creation
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

#### Another Round of a solution

```py
class Tableserializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tables
        exclude=('author',)
    
    def validate_tablerequireDate(self, data):
         try:
              # do validation
         except ValidationError:
              raise Validation.....
         else:
              return validated_data
```